# If you can send thousands of dollars on the Internet, why not ballots?

Tags: bitcoin

To my understanding, Bitcoin can be sent quickly, anonymously, and fairly safely. But if you don’t need to spend physical notes (or in the case of debit cards, redeem your money for physical notes) why not vote on little, ethereal ballots you can send on a wire?

You would still have a secret ballot if you use a phony IP address, right? So why doesn’t it work that way?

Answer (score 0):

First, because (many) governments are slow to adapt new technologies.

Second, you have some difficulties to solve. You have to ensure that everyone who is entitled to vote, can vote secretly and only once, and that it is not possible to relate the vote to the voter.

The IP address is less a concern if cryptographically done right.
So the questions might be better suited in another sub, but I try to get you a rough idea.

So you need a way to distribute a kind of token to all entitled persons, securely. How do you know who is entitled? With a central register. Then everyone would have to get a digital ID to which the token is send, kind of bitcoin wallet. How do you get the address of the id? Generate it centrally shall not be done, because then they would have the private keys of the id, which opens doors to manipulation. So the voters need to generate their keys themselves, and have the public key send to the register.
But you still have to solve people loosing their keys, due to broken phone or whatever, securely, so nobody can send a new key for another person to steal the vote token.
And last but not least, have a way to submit the ballot, like signed with the private key, but in a way you cannot relate what the person voted, but still that the person has voted and in a way that the ballot is secure so you cannot insert faked ballots.

I'm not a cryptographic expert, I guess there are ways to solve that, but it's difficult and will be expensive if done right.
And because it's expensive, there is no motivation for government to do so, and there is much potential for critical errors so that system needs to be thoroughly tested to be approved.

And such a system, if done right, would make it possible to publish ballots to enable public election monitoring - and that might not be in the interest of the government.